# Counting lines in Swift

Tags: swift

Apple's [Text Layout Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html) contains the following fragment of Objective-C code to count the number of lines in an NSString.

```
NSString *string;
unsigned numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [string length];
for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < stringLength; numberOfLines++)
    index = NSMaxRange([string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
```

What would the Swift equivalent be using native String?

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried so far, so that it does not look like a "translate this code for me" question?

Comment: I have written little Swift code so I may be wrong in believing that the challenge of manipulating ranges of String.Index is complex, but I would like to learn from the best approach to this problem rather than a variant of my possibly poor approach.

Comment: Worst case scenario, the "Swift equivalent" could be to put this in a function, import the file it's in to your bridging hear, and call the ObjC C-style function from Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem I found so I will leave it here in case someone else finds it useful.

```
var text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
for var range = text.startIndex...text.startIndex; range.endIndex < text.endIndex;
        range = range.endIndex..<range.endIndex {
    range = text.lineRangeForRange(range)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is (just a plain translation of the guide you posted):

```
func countLines(textView: UITextView) -> Int {
    let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    var numberOfLines = 0
    var index = 0
    var lineRange = NSRange()
    var numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
    for(numberOfLines, index; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++){
        layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    return numberOfLines
}
```

or, if you need a specific range in your textcode (like me):

```
func countLinesInRange(textView: UITextView, range: NSRange) -> Int{
    let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    var numberOfLines = 0
    var index = range.location
    var lineRange = range
    var numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
    for(numberOfLines, index; index < range.location+range.length; numberOfLines++){
        layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    return numberOfLines
}
```